# Editing Contribution Page

Tags: webform-civicrm

I am trying to change the message on my Perdue Credit Debit Contribution Page under "Leadership Giving" & edit the receipt message sent to donor.

Comment: hi and welcome. 'webform_civicrm' is a specific Drupal module. do you mean that? if not, and you mean a standard civicrm contribution page, do you see the receipt text in your 'thank you and receipting' tab, eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/contribute/thankyou?reset=1&action=update&id=1

Comment: if not, then perhaps the text you are looking for is at /civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1&selectedChild=workflow and look to see if the "Contributions - Receipt (on-line)" one has been customised. if it has you should see "Edit | Revert to Default | View Default" if it has not then you should just see 'Edit'